# How to integrate MapMyIndia SDK in AOSP 13?

Tags: android, android-source, android-13, custom-rom, mapmyindia-api

I'm building custom AOSP ROM. I would like develop my own navigation/map application inside AOSP. How can I use/integrate MapMyIndia SDK in AOSP ?